# Updating Android Studio from 2.1.2 to 2.2 - Could not find Data Binding Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.databinding:library:1.2.1.
Required by:
    XYZAPP:app:unspecified
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. Update *Android Support Repository* to **rev. 38** in Android SDK fixed that  issue for me. 
Previously I updated *Android SDK Tools*, *Android SDK Platform-tools* to latest versions and install *Android 7.0 SDK Platform*, this also may help.